# Function call prefers const reference over r-value reference

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I am currently playing around with move semantics in C++. I tried to use r-value references in a custom constructor. Please see the following simplified example:

```
class MyClass
{
   public:
      // ....
      MyClass(MyClass&& pLeft, int pOp, MyClass&& pRight);
      MyClass(const MyClass& pLeft, int pOp, const MyClass& pRight);
      // ....
};

MyClass operator +(MyClass&& pLeft, MyClass&& pRight)
{
   return MyClass(pLeft, 1, pRight);
}
```

The `operator+` is called as expected with `pLeft` and `pRight` being temporary objects. However then it calls the custom constructor using l-value references instead of the custom constructor using r-value references. Why?

There is a *lot* of information about r-value references and move semantics in the web. But it seems I skipped the detail that explains the mentioned behaviour.

Comment: `pLeft` is not a temporary (because it has a name). You need to `std::move`. Yes, expression vs variable types are confusing.

Comment: Remember, if something has a name, it is an lvalue.  That is a important thing to remember when dealing with rvalue references and move semantics.